# How to perform a low level disk copy? (Migrate Windows system from one disk to the other)

Tags: ssd, operating-systems

Currently, I have a SSD on my computer, I install my OS Windows 7 on it. Unfortunately, it's capability is too small (32GB), it gets full easily, I need to clean up files periodically, it's quite annoying. To solve the problem, I want to buy another SSD which has larger capability, but I don't want to reinstall Windows 7 on the new SSD and all other softwares on it. I prefer to copy everything on my old SSD to the new one.

Here comes the problem, to do a low level SSD copy, I have no idea how to do, what kind of tool I can use, what kind of problem I may encounter. I'm worrying about the original configuration in Windows 7, it tells which disk windows be installed, if Windows 7 found itself is in a different disk after boot, what will happen? Will something go wrong?

Or, is there any better way to migrate windows system from my original SSD to the new one?

Thanks.

Comment: Windows might complain about the move, but you can shut it up by giving it the Product Key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to do this using the linux graphical application [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/). In the documentation there is a guide on [how to move/copy partitions using this application](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/larry/move/move.htm).

[image]
*Image extracted from gparted documentation*

You can get gparted from many livecd linux distributions, I particularly like [KNOPPIX](http://www.knoppix.org/) for this kind of maintenance tasks.